# angular + requirejs: quick refreshing pages cause page stop working in chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

during the development with angular + requirejs. I met a weird problem.

if I quick refresh page(like pressing F5), after a few times, I will get the following error message and the page is not working any more even refresh the page again, unless clean the cache and open the page on new tab:

```
Error: $digest already in progress
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at beginPhase (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:8495:15)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:8297:11)
    at done (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9357:20)
    at completeRequest (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9520:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9490:11)
    at http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9499:11
    at sendReq (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9333:9)
    at $http (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9124:17)
    at Function.$http.(anonymous function) (http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/assets/vendor/angular/angular.js:9267:18)
```

this error seem to only happen in chrome. I try to trigger it on IE and Firefox, it was not happening. however, I try it in chrome on slow computer, it also not happen.

the computer which I triggered this issue has i7 cpu, 8gb ram.angular I using is 1.0.8.

I attached my code which isolated this issue. my project code is more complex then this, so less times to trigger it. the isolated code may requires press more few times on F5 to trigger the issue.

the isolated example code: [Link](http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/#/)

how to trigger the bug: [video](http://www.caoglish.info/angular_bug/video.html)

quick pressing F5 until it happen.

I create a issue post on angular project: [Link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4771)

Comment: While I'm not saying that there might not be a problem here. It took you 30s of F5ing like a maniac to get that error. Would that be an accurate representation of it's use?

Comment: number of times of pressing is random. sometimes more, sometimes less, sometimes only pressing 2-3 times. also this is isolated code, so it may be the reason I need to pressing more times. but on my project code only press several times.

Comment: during the development, I may refresh page to see the result, sometime, I pressing F5 very quick.if trigger the issue , I will confuse to know which part of my code cause the problem. I can get a video which less than 10 seconds, but video just show how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please try it with current developer version of Chrome. I had a very similar issue which was present on Chrome. One or two weeks ago it was resolved on developer version. Stable is still broken. I couldn't find a issue reported but It seems like a bug.

Comment: Your links are broken... care to use jsfiddle/plunkr ?

Answer (score 1):

This question may be dead, but I've seen the same behavior. And it's definitely not an Angular issue. It's just a simple race condition, and it's more or less unavoidable. When you hit F5, the browser halts everything going on in the "sandbox" for security reasons: standard requests for things like IMG content, XHR requests, the main thread your Angular code runs in, etc. It's extremely fast but not instant, and if you work hard to disrupt it, you succeed.

IMO the root question here should be whether this is "bad", and to me, that means does it either a) create a security vulnerability, or b) do something that could corrupt important data.

You can rule out the first because only code already running in the browser at the moment F5 was pressed could POSSIBLY try to exploit whatever edge cases come out of the race condition here. And if it's already running in the browser, it can do anything it wants because it's already "within the walls" so to speak.

You can rule out the second because you aren't supposed to design Web apps that require 100% confidence that the next line of code will be executed... because you know that's never certain. The user could just close the browser any time they wanted to, and once you assume that you have to code in such a way to tolerate these kinds of conditions anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you long response, It's kind of proving my opinion of chromes' issue. I made work around this issue at that time and seem to work. I use like script.js?bust=timestamp (tiempstamp always changing) to force browser reload all the js files every time, although I don't like the solution. I wish the bug of chrome can be fixed.